# Вопрос по лексической сочетаемости

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

Как правильно: "это выступление стало одиозным" или "это слово стало одиозным"? В толковом словаре Кузнецова есть пример "это слово стало одиозным", но почему выступление не может быть одиозным? Какое здесь правило? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В целом никаких особенных проблем с сочетаемостью, разве что слово изначально латинское.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Это выступление стало одиозным" - здесь полный порядок. Но иностранное слово "одиозный" имеет разностороннее понимание. Например: у всех на слуху или показатель облыжности.